# Unable to deploy mysql debezium connector on GKE - User does not have the 'LOCK TABLES' privileges

Tags: mysql, docker, google-kubernetes-engine, debezium

We are deploying Debezium [mysql-cdc-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/v2/cdc-parent#deploying-the-connector) on GKE. After the deployment the pod is failing with following error:

> caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: User does not have the 'LOCK TABLES' privilege required to obtain a consistent snapshot by preventing concurrent writes to tables.

To overcome this without giving lock table access to the user, we can set `snapshot.locking.mode=none`. But we are not able to figure out where to update the code [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/tree/master/v2/cdc-parent#deploying-the-connector).

Answer (score 2):

In order to set this configuration you should add `"snapshot.locking.mode": "none",` in your json configuration file and proceed with the steps described in [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-adding-configuration) in order to start running a MySQL connector.

Please remind to configure a connector configuration, and add the configuration to your Kafka Connect cluster.